# SQL - Filter rows by attributes

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables USERS, WORKFLOWS, ATTRIBUTES. WORKFLOWS tables values will be NEW, UPDATE and DELETE and ATTRIBUTES table contains workflow attributes like comment, doneBy, dateOfDone etc there are many. Users and Workflows table are connected by USR_ID and workflows and Attributes are connected by WF_ID.

```
+--------+------------+------------+    +--------+---------+------------+
|USR_ID  | USR_NAME   | IS_GENUINE |    |WF_ID   | WF_NAME | USR_ID     |
+--------|------------+------------+    +--------|---------+------------+
| 1      |  John      |   Y        |    | 1      |  NEW    |   1        |
| 2      |  King      |   Y        |    | 2      |  Update |   1        |
| 3      |  Mark      |   N        |    | 3      |  Delete |   1        |
| 4      |  Smith     |   N        |    | 4      |  Delete |   2        |
| 5      |  Zack      |   Y        |    | 5      |  Update |   2        |
+---------------------+------------+    | 6      |  New    |   3        |
                                        | 7      |  Update |   5        |
                                        +------------------+------------+
+--------+--------------+----------------+-------+
|ATTR_ID | ATTR_NAME   | ATTR_VALUE      | WF_ID |
+--------|------------- +----------------+-------+
| 1      |  comment     |   good         |  1    |
| 2      |  doneBy      |   suresh       |  1    |
| 3      |  comment     |   good         |  2    |
| 4      |  doneBy      |   suresh       |  2    |
| 5      |  comment     |   bad          |  3    |
| 6      |  doneBy      |   Raj          |  3    |
| 7      |  comment     |   Wow          |  4    |
| 8      |  doneBy      |   Amit         |  4    |
| 9      |  comment     |   good         |  7    |
| 10     |  doneBy      |   suresh       |  7    |
+-----------------------+----------------+-------+
```

Now comes the major question I want to fetch the user info along with workflows and attributes if the IS_GENUINE = 'y' and comment = 'good' and doneBy = 'suresh'.

**Expected Output**

```
+--------+------------+---------+-----------+------------+
|USR_ID  | USR_NAME   | WF_NAME | ATTR_NAME | ATTR_VALUE |
+--------|------------+---------+-----------|------------+
| 1      |  John      |  NEW    |  comment  | good       |
+--------|------------+---------+-----------|------------+
| 1      |  John      |  NEW    |  doneBy   | suresh     |
+--------|------------+---------+-----------|------------+
| 1      |  John      |  UPDATE |  comment  | good       |
+--------|------------+---------+-----------|------------+
| 1      |  John      |  UPDATE |  doneBy   | suresh     |
+--------|------------+---------+-----------|------------+
| 1      |  John      |  DELETE |  comment  | bad        |
+--------|------------+---------+-----------|------------+
| 1      |  John      |  DELETE |  doneBy   | Raj        |
+--------|------------+---------+-----------|------------+
| 5      |  Zack      |  UPDATE |  comment  | good       |
+--------|------------+---------+-----------|------------+
| 5      |  Zack      |  UPDATE |  doneBy   | suresh     |
+--------|------------+---------+-----------|------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use windows function `count` as follows:

```
Select USR_ID, USR_NAME, WF_NAME, ATTR_NAME, ATTR_VALUE from
(Select U.USR_ID, U.USR_NAME, W.WF_NAME, A.ATTR_NAME, A.ATTR_VALUE, 
        count(case when a.attr_name = 'comment' and attr_value = 'good' then 1 end) over (partition by a.wf_id) as comm_cnt,
        count(case when a.attr_name = 'doneBy' and attr_value = 'suresh' then 1 end) over (partition by a.wf_id) as suresh_cnt
from
Users u join workflow w
On u.user_id = w.user_id
Join attributes a on a.wf_id = w.wf_id
Where is_genuine = 'Y')
Where comm_cnt = 1 and suresh_cnt = 1;
```

Comment: What about IS_GENUINE = 'y' condition?

Comment: yeap. Updated answer.

Comment: From select statement in line 1 i.e Select <column_list> from -> how do I show column values from all 3 tables ? Can you update the query accordingly. And also I don't want to show comm_cnt and suresh_cnt as part of select. Anyway to do that ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT user_id, usr_name, wf_name, attr_name, attr_value
FROM users AS u JOIN attributes AS a ON u.user_id = a.user_id , workflows
    JOIN attr_value ON b.wf_id = c.wf_id
WHERE is_genuine = 'y' AND
    (attr_name = 'comment' AND attr_value = 'good') OR
    (attr_name = 'doneBy' AND attr_value = 'suresh');
```

P.S. I would restructure `ATTRIBUTES`. Try this:

```
+--------+---------+----------+-------+
|ATTR_ID | COMMENT | BY       | WF_ID |
+--------|---------+----------+-------+
| 1      |  good   |  suresh  |  1    |
| 2      |  good   |  suresh  |  2    |
| 3      |  bad    |  Raj     |  3    |
| 4      |  Wow    |  Amit    |  4    |
| 5      |  good   |  suresh  |  7    |
+------------------+----------+-------+
```

Then the query can look like this:

```
SELECT user_id, usr_name, wf_name, attr_name, attr_value
FROM users AS u JOIN attributes AS a ON u.user_id = a.user_id , workflows
    JOIN attr_value ON b.wf_id = c.wf_id
WHERE is_genuine = 'y' AND
    (comment = 'good' AND by = 'suresh');
```

Results will look like this:

```
+---------+----------+---------+---------+--------+
| usr_id  | usr_name | wf_name | comment | by     |
+---------|----------+---------+---------|--------+
|  1      |  John    |  new    |  good   | suresh |
|  1      |  John    |  update |  good   | suresh |
|  1      |  John    |  delete |  bad    | Raj    |
|  5      |  Zack    |  update |  good   | suresh |
+---------|----------+---------+---------|--------+
```

Comment: The first query you mentioned **FROM users AS u JOIN attributes AS a ON u.user_id = a.user_id ** attributes doesn't have user_id field

Comment: I cannot modify the Attributes table because attributes will be dynamic in nature for now I mentioned comment and by for simplicity.